# 'MAT_DIALOG_DATA' was not found in '@angular/material'

Tags: angular

My project was building ok at one time, but after trying to fix a problem it is no longer building.  I might have upgraded, downgraded, deleted node_modules folder, deleted dist folder... I don't remember.  Now when I do **ng build** I'm getting

> ./src/app/my.component.ts:148:188-203 - Error: export
> 'MAT_DIALOG_DATA' (imported as 'MAT_DIALOG_DATA') was not found in
> '@angular/material' (possible exports:
> ɵɵtsModuleIndicatorApiExtractorWorkaround).

Inside my.component.ts there is a

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

constructor( private myService: MyService,
             @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
```

It would seem 'MAT_DIALOG_DATA' is not available in the version of @angular/material that I’m using.

Here is my angular version info:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.13
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.13
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, router

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1202.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular       12.2.13
@angular-devkit/core                12.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics          12.2.13
@angular/cdk                        12.2.2
@angular/material                   12.2.2
@angular/material-moment-adapter    12.2.2
@angular/platform-browser           12.2.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   12.2.2
@schematics/angular                 12.2.13 (cli-only)
ng-packagr                          12.2.5
rxjs                                6.6.7
typescript                          4.3.5
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you want to import it from material/dialog : 
`import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';`

Comment: Did you import the ` MatDialogModule ` in your app.module.ts file? ``` import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog'; ``` and  ```  @NgModule({ ...,    imports: [ ...,  MatDialogModule  ], )}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should inject it from `@angular/material/dialog`

```
import {MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

check the examples

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Yea, it looks like newer version of angular moved it from /material to /material/dialog, causing all of our code to break.  Many other things broken now as well.  How aggravating that they do that.  Very fearful of upgrading to new releases!

Comment: @humble I wouldn't consider changing imports like this fearful..

Answer (score 0):

Add this please

```
     import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```